# How to confirm Solr is running from the command line?

Tags: command-line, solr

We have a few servers that are going to be rebooted soon and I may have to restart Apache Solr manually.

How can I verify (from the command line) that Solr is running?

Comment: ps -ef | grep start.jar

Comment: why not just curl with the solr url !

Comment: @mbaxi I have a server that is running solr, but `ps` doesn't return a result. I'm not sure how solr was started.

Answer (score 10):

The proper way is to use Solr's [STATUS](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#STATUS) command. You could parse its XML response, but as long as it returns something to you with an HTTP status of *200*, it should be safe to assume it's running. You can perform an HTTP HEAD request using [curl](https://superuser.com/a/442395/52739) with:

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -I -w '%{http_code}' http://example.com:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS
```

- NOTE: Also, you can add a `-m <seconds>` to the command to only wait so many *seconds* for a response.

This will make a request to the Solr admin interface, and print out `200` on success which can be used from a bash script such as:

```bash
RESULT=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -I -w '%{http_code}' http://example.com:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS)
if [ "$RESULT" -eq '200' ]; then
    # Solr is running...
else
    # Solr is not running...
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are on the same machine where Solr is running then this is my favourite:

```
$> solr status
```

Comment: /path/to/solr/bin/solr status